# .Net dual authentication methods in a web application

Tags: asp.net, linux, windows, authentication, shibboleth

First off, I'm completely new to Shibboleth and SAML.  We have a ..net web application which uses the .net membership provider functionality for forms authentication.  We need to keep the .net mode of authenticating.  However, we've now been asked to add the ability to authenticate a user coming from another web application which uses Shibboleth.

My question is, and I apologize if it sounds stupid, but can a .net web application implement both the 'default' asp membership and shibboleth authentication, or does it have to be one or the other?

Our web app is a .net 4.5 written in vb.net and hosted on Windows server.  The other is a web app written in PHP (if I'm not mistaken) uses Shibboleth and is on a Linux server.
Thanks!